# VMWare or Hyper-V Maximum Guest (30TB) Storage

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v

Between MS Hyper-V 2012 and VMWare Esxi-5.1 (Free version), which one would give/allow me Maximum local storage? In other words I would like to create a Virtual Host which will host may be couple of guests VMs and one of them will be a MS storage server 2012. I would like to be able to store up to 30TB of media files. I have Dell PE R720XD server. Can I do it with one server?

OR

I would have to have another server which will host the virtual VM guests and make R720 a sort of storage appliance?

Comment: Does it make sense to virtualize with such a lopsided requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both hypervisors can provide 30TB of storage to a single guest VM.

Comment: Hello, so I should be good with Dell R720XD for installing Hypervisor and installing VMs on the same hardware?

Comment: I'm more of a VMWare guy than HV but if you're doing it on ESXi 5.x then read this first so you don't make a mistake; http://www.vmware.com/pdf/esx25_rawdevicemapping.pdf